# how to draw control on canvas using mobile touch while having scroll on screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, mobile

I'm trying to create a mobile app in which user can draw multiple controls (rectangle) on a canvas.

It works fine if canvas fits the screen, but the controls are not drawn well when I increase the canvas height and width out of the screen (a scroll appear when i increase the size of canvas more than the size of mobile screen).
How to fix this in scroll mode?

> Use Chrome Inspect mobile view (iPhone 6/7/8) to test this code
>   Use Pointer drag to draw controls

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas_transparent" height="3000" width="1000" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_transparent");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var endX;
var startX;
var endY;
var startY;
var positions = [];
//--------------------------------------------------------
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
  mousePos = getTouchPos(canvas, e);
  startX = mousePos.x;
  startY = mousePos.y;
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);
//---------------------------------------------------------
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  positions.push({
    s_x: startX,
    s_y: startY,
    e_x: endX,
    e_y: endY
  });
  drawAllControls();
  console.log(positions);
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);
//---------------------------------------------------------
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  endX = touch.clientX;
  endY = touch.clientY;
  drawSquare()
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);
//--------------------------------------------------------
// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
  };
}
//--------------------------------------------------------
function drawSquare() {
  // creating a square
  var w = endX - startX;
  var h = endY - startY;
  var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
  var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
  var width = Math.abs(w);
  var height = Math.abs(h);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(startX + offsetX, startY + offsetY, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
}
//----------------------------------------------------------
function drawAllControls() {
  for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    var w = positions[i].e_x - positions[i].s_x;
    var h = positions[i].e_y - positions[i].s_y;
    var offsetX = (w < 0) ? w : 0;
    var offsetY = (h < 0) ? h : 0;
    var width = Math.abs(w);
    var height = Math.abs(h);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(positions[i].s_x + offsetX, positions[i].s_y + offsetY, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#222222";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}
</script>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: When the canvas is bigger than the screen, should a swipe create a rectangle or scroll the screen?

Comment: at my side, your code is not working at all

Comment: I only works on mobile device mode. you can us inspect element and toggle to Device mode !

Answer (score 3):

`clientX`/`clientY` do not factor in scroll offset. I think you want `pageX`/`pageY`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch

```
// Get the position of a touch relative to the canvas
function getTouchPos(canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].pageX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].pageY - rect.top
  };
}
```

Comment: This is not working..., please check the code in browser mobile view mode. you will get what the exact problem is

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this will resolve your problem. Put this in the head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

working link [page](https://codingexceptions.com/wkwebview/rahul.html)

[image]

Comment: I don't want to change height and width of the Canvas. and in my case height and width is 4 times greater than mobile view. and i want to create controls on canvas on the screen that is out of the screen size. The Demo page that you provide also have the same issue like i have in my code.

Comment: Increase the width and height of canvas out of the screen and try to draw control on outside screen area (area which is after the scrolling). you also will get the same issue !!!

Comment: You can enable default zoom controls on the webview so that you will achieve  desired functionality.